# How does restaurant website hide file extension in address bar and code in DevTools?

Tags: web

I really like the website for the restaurant Cafe Rio.  However the developers have done 2 interesting things and I'm not sure how they accomplished them.

**Effect 1:** 
Visit the [menu page](https://www.caferio.com/menu).

In the address bar of your browser you will see,

```
https://www.caferio.com/menu
```

Why isn't a file extension listed?  For example `menu.htm`.  Are they hiding the extension somehow?  Is there some other obvious trick that can accomplish this?

**Effect 2:** On the same menu page click F12 to open DevTools.

I opened DevTools to see if I could figure out how they hid the file extension. Inside I found another mystery. Listed in order I see:

```
www.caferio.com
  css
  img
  js
  menu
```

I assume `menu` is the main document but inside of that doc I don't see any code whatsoever.  All that I see is a yellow warning about the SSL certificate.  WOW!  How are they hiding their code?  Thanks so much for any input!

**--UPDATE--**

For some reason I can now see the code inside menu and it's standard looking HTML. But I still don't see a file extension at the end of menu.  How did they make that work?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Effect 1:**
The extension isn't needed when you use a http-server like apache,
you can type "rewrite rules" in a special file (.htaccess) to specify the target of any links on your page to a specified target:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

In the entry-file "index.php" you code what the program should do with the request.

But in many cases you don't recreate the whole system, instead you install an CMS like wordpress to manage your page.

**Effect 2:**
They don't hide any code from you, the code for any effected file can be visited in the *debugger* tab. But it is minified with post-process-transformer like css-minifier and jsuglify.

Comment: Alright super interesting.  I understand `.htaccess` but I'm not entirely sure how that would help in this situation.  For example lets say I'm on the homepage and I click the `menu` link.  It's easy to understand how `menu.htm` would work, but how would `.htaccess` make `menu` with no file extension work?  Thanks so much!

Comment: In DevTools I found this code inside the menu page, `<a href="https://www.caferio.com/locations">Locations</a>`

Comment: the RewriteRule specifies how apache (your webserver) transform the request and which file it should call (redirect).
When you rewrite any request to your server (^.*$ is matching everything) to the index.php, you can handle the "path" (e.g. /menu) within the php programmcode.

Comment: Every request to the server can be handled by the business logic of php programs (including css, images, audio, fonts, videos, etc.) but in most cases, you just fill some templates with data and texts.

Comment: I've just done a quick search on google and this seems to be a good start to dive into htaccess/mod_rewrite (just in case, you need some more knowledge): https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners